# Excessive message size with boost asio and SSL

Tags: c++, boost, ssl

I am currently working on a server that uses SSL to secure the transmissions. After accepting a conenction, the server makes the hadshake and if it succeeds, it sends a packet to the client.

My code is working perfectly fine on Windows, but when I run it on Debian 7, I get an "Excessive message size" error when I try to write that packet.

I'm pretty sure it does not come from my certificates, since I tried running the boost asio SSL  example with the same certificates and it works perfectly fine.

Here is the code:

Initialization of the server:

```
Server::Server(configuration::Configuration const & conf, utils::Logger & log): _cmds(conf, log), _conf(conf), _logger(log), _ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23)
{
tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), conf.getPort());
configuration::SSL_conf ssl = conf.getSLLInfos();

try
{
    this->_ctx.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
    | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
    | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
    this->_ctx.set_password_callback(boost::bind(&Server::_getPass, this, _1, _2));
    this->_ctx.use_certificate_file(ssl.certificate.string(), boost::asio::ssl::context_base::pem);
    this->_ctx.use_private_key_file(ssl.key.string(), boost::asio::ssl::context_base::pem);
    this->_ctx.use_tmp_dh_file(ssl.certificate.string());
    this->_acceptor.reset(new tcp::acceptor(this->_service, endpoint));
    this->_logger.logMsg(3, "Starting listen on port " + std::to_string(endpoint.port()));
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        this->_c.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Client>(new Client(this->_service, this->_cmds, conf, log, i, this->_ctx)));
    this->_acceptor->async_accept(this->_c.front()->getSocket(),
        boost::bind(&Server::_handleAccept, this,
        this->_c.front(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
catch (boost::system::system_error & err)
{
    this->_logger.logErr(err.what());
}
}
```

The initialization of the session:

```
void                    Client::init()
{
this->_logger.logMsg(3, "Client [" + std::to_string(this->_id) + "] initialized");
this->_isAlive = true;
this->_socket.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server,
    boost::bind(&Client::handleHandshake, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

The handhsake callback:

```
void                    Client::handleHandshake(boost::system::error_code const & err)
{
if (!err)
{
    memset(&this->_header, 0, sizeof(protocol::header));
    this->_keepAlive = this->_conf.getKeepAlive();
    this->_header.keepAlive = 1;
    this->_logger.logStruct<protocol::header>("Client [" + std::to_string(this->_id) + "] Sending handhsake: ", this->_header);
    boost::asio::async_write(this->_socket, boost::asio::buffer(&this->_header, sizeof(protocol::header)),
        boost::bind(&Client::handleWrite, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
else
    this->kill();
}
```

And finally, the write callback where I receive the error:

```
void                    Client::handleWrite(boost::system::error_code const & err, std::size_t)
{
if (!err && this->_keepAlive)
{
    clearBuff(this->_outBuff);
    boost::asio::async_read(this->_socket, boost::asio::buffer(&this->_header, sizeof(protocol::header)),
        boost::bind(&Client::handleHeaderRead, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
else
{
    this->_logger.logErr("Client [" + std::to_string(this->_id) + "] write failed : " + err.message());
    this->kill();
}
}
```

As I said the handleWrite callback receives an error with the value "Excessive message size". I really don't understand why since my use of boost asio is pretty standard and my certificates, that are self signed work with other applications.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Try to configure a specific SSL protocol version (e.g. only SSLv3). This reduces the list of items to be sent. Also, consider sending a minimized certificate bundle (in the certificate file on the server) because the client won't be interested in most root certificates in the chain, unless it already knows them anyways

Comment: Wow! I cannot believe that solved it. All I did was change the initialization parameter of the ssl_context from sslv23 to sslv3 and it works like a charm. Thanks mate!

Comment: I have posted it as an answer :/ Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configure a specific SSL protocol version (e.g. only SSLv3). This reduces the list of items to be sent.

Also, consider sending a minimized certificate bundle (in the certificate file on the server) because the client won't be interested in most root certificates in the chain, unless it already knows them anyways

Answer (score 1):

From your description, the problem is not with the SSL handshake itself, but with the buffer in the call to `async_write` in `Client::handleHandshake`.

I'd recommend logging both `sizeof(_header)` and `sizeof(protocol::header)` and comparing them in both implementations.

BTW where do you allocate the memory for `_header`? Is it done in the Constructor? Because it's not done in `Client::init()`

Comment: _header is a standard C-style structure with ints and char inside. It represents the header for the packets of the protocol I'm using. By the way _header is of type protocol::header and it's size os the same on both windows and debian. Since it is not a pointer, the memory is allocated at the object construction by the system.

Comment: In which case your problem may be caused by your Windows and Debian compiliers using different alignment for the byte layout of protocol::header.

Comment: The [alignas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) specifier, or corresponding `#pragma` should be used to ensure the layout of the struct.  Otherwise, the compiler is free to pad it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I've tried sending a classic buffer (char *) instead of a struct and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so as said in a comment, the problem was that for some reason, letting the client and server decide which version to choose from seemed to screw things up. By forcing the use of SSLV3, it solve it. Thank you all for your help though.

Comment: It's probably not about "forcing the choice", but merely that narrowing the list of choices makes the actual handshake packets smaller